# Fluent Security Custom Policy

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, fluent-security

I am using Fluent Security in a MVC5 application.  I Created a custom policy called RequirePortalRole().  For testing purposes i and always returning a success.

My security configuration is as follows

```
            configuration.ForAllControllers().DenyAnonymousAccess();
            configuration.For<AccountController>(x => x.LogOn()).Ignore();
            configuration.For<HomeController>().AddPolicy(new RequirePortalRole());
```

Since RequiredPortalRole() Always returns PolicyResult.CreateSuccessResult(this); i would expect that i could access anything on the home controller but nothing else except for the LogOn action in the Account Controller.  The custom policy does not appear to be over riding the ForAllController policy.

Any idea why not? Am i actually applying two polices to the HomeController ?

Answer (score 2):

Policies are added and everyone of them is enforced for every request. I think that if you want to access everything on HomeController you should explicity remove the policy:

```
        configuration.For<HomeController>()
            .RemovePolicy<DenyAnonymousAccessPolicy>()
            .AddPolicy<RequirePortalRole>();
```

I hope I got your question right.

Comment: I can confirm what @Hernan suggests is the correct solution.